# Can't connect to qbittorrent (or other client) Web UI, except through localhost

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, remote, bittorrent, dd-wrt

I'm trying to use qBittorrent's (I've also tried other torrent clients') remote Web UI, but can't seem to get it to work. I can connect just fine using `http://localhost:PORT`, but can't connect using `http://MYIP:PORT`. For MYIP, I've tried using both the one assigned by my router and the IP of my router.

I have Xfinity/Comcast and set up port forwarding, turned off Windows firewall, but neither of those seemed to work. Since that didn't work, I had my Xfinity router put into bridge mode and then connected another router with DD-WRT. I set up port forwarding there and still couldn't get it to work. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

In troubleshooting, I looked at DD-WRT's logs and it looks like the Comcast router *might* be changing my port into upnp or another port, depending on which one I'm trying to access it with. In the log, the status says "Dropped". I don't know if that helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you disabled that option, qBittorrent adds an exception rule into the Windows firewall during setup. qBittorrent can enable the forwarding rule automatically through UPnP, visit the `/UPnP.asp` page on your DD-WRT router to see if it works. This is also where you could check if UPnP is even enabled.

Comment: I tried with the UPnP option enabled and disabled in qBittorrent, but still no luck. I'm away from my router now while I'm at work, but I'll make sure to check the `/UPnP.asp` page when I get home.

Comment: @user2773449: You did some pretty good analysis so far, you should just be more methodical and not toggle settings on and off wildly. If you can connect through `localhost` that tells you the service in itself is working. Next step would be (as you've already tested yourself) accessing the Web UI locally through your computers LAN IP address. If that doesn't work, then there's no need to change anything on your router, it will be a local issue. A disabled Windows Firewall can have weird side effects. Leave it enabled and look specifically for rules that might impact your problem.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: You're definitely right on needing to be more methodical. Before I tried disabling the firewall entirely, I *did* try adding exceptions in the windows firewall rules (created specific rules to allow traffic through that port) and that didn't work either, unfortunately. Maybe I'm setting up port forwarding wrong in the DD-WRT? Any tips? I am new to setting up port forwarding in DD-WRT...

Comment: When you're trying to access a service on your computer, through the IP address of that same computer, then it's not an issue with your router.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: What might it be?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. First I tested if IP:8080 works over local network (from a different computer) when I disabled the Firewall on the host machine. That worked!

I re-enabled the Firewall, went to `Setting [search] > Allow an app through Windows` or via `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed apps` and enabled the checkbox on the Local column for qBittorrent.

Now it works with Firewall enabled.